# How do I hide partial text in a UserForm text box while keeping the full text pastable?

Tags: excel, vba, hide, userform

I pull cells from a spreadsheet to a textbox in Excel. They are numbers with spaces in between them, and I want to format that text to only show the last four digits while having the whole value still be able to be pulled from that textbox. Is this possible?

Comment: You could put the original, unformatted value into the tag property and then use regex to format the value into the text property.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Can you go into more detail about how that works?

Comment: I recall from your last question that this value is a credit card number.  Is that still the case?

Comment: "pulled from that textbox" - what exactly does that mean?  Copy for pasting?  If you can copy/paste the whole value a plain text then why hide any of the characters?

Comment: @BrianMStafford yes it is. im trying to figure out a way to keep my sensitive data secure but also able to be marked which company card was used for a transaction.

Comment: @BrianMStafford is there a more secure way that you would suggest to keep track of that?

Comment: Side note, but this should not be considered "secure" by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TextBox has a Tag property where you can store the original value before you format the value as needed.  For example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   Dim CreditCard As String

   CreditCard = "1234 5678 1234 5678" 'or a cell value

   TextBox1.Tag = CreditCard
   TextBox1.Text = MaskCreditCard(CreditCard)
End Sub

Private Function MaskCreditCard(ByVal CreditCard As String) As String
   'set a Reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
   Dim regEx As RegExp
   
   'there are many patterns you can choose
   Set regEx = New RegExp
   regEx.Global = True
   regEx.Pattern = "[0-9](?=.*.{4})"
   
   MaskCreditCard = regEx.Replace(CreditCard, "*")
End Function
```

This produces:

[image]

You could choose any display format but I would opt for what I showed above.  The original value is available in the Tag property.